# Dyanamically choose js files to download

Tags: javascript

I have a js client.
Currently I have a single *app.js* file which is a concatenation of all my *js* files.
Therefore in my html file I reference only one *js* file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

However, for debugging purposes I would like my client to download all the original *js* files and use them instead.
However, since I have a lot of files I don't want to add them manually. I would like to:

1. Iterate all files in a folder.
2. Select the *js* files.
3. Download only those files.

Regarding the 3rd item - I think I know how to do that - so my main question is how do I iterate the files in order to select the interesting ones.

Comment: You can't do this with only JavaScript. JS has no access to your file directories.

Comment: Consider using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for these type of things. You can separate your production and development environments and auto-concatenate files on save etc..

Comment: I would also recommend Grunt. You may enjoy developing your applications using Require.js, too. It may be a lot of work retrofitting a very large, mature application, but it does everything you need. During development, it auto-loads (via dependency declarations) only the files you need. And when you are ready for production, there is a custom optimizer ('R.js') that builds a single JS file. The best thing is that you can use the same library of modules for multiple applications and as long as you are careful about your dependency declarations, it will only load what it actually needs.